# ft_min_word_len in MySQL on SHARED SERVER

Tags: mysql

I was wondering if it is possible to adjust the variable ft_min_word_len in MySQL on a SHARED SERVER. The default value is 4, i need to change it to 2, i have spoken with my hosting company they say they cant change.

So my question is can it be changed using ini_set in PHP or something in .htaccess ?

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ft_min_word` is a setting of the MySQL server. You cannot therefore change it in the `ini_set` (which isfor PHP).
The server is a seperate thing, and if your host has multiple users using the same server (which is standard on a shared server), they will use the same setting.

The same goes for a `.htaccess` setting: this can only change how `apache` will react (if allowed to change), not how the database server is configured.

The variable, described [here in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len) is not a [dynamic variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/dynamic-system-variables.html) that can be set in runtime

Comment: So there is no other alternative?

Comment: Nope, it is not dynamic. let me add something

Comment: Here http://www.dbforumz.com/Problem-ft_min_word_len-ftopict138412.html some has given a solution i tried but its not working

Comment: This is not a sollution to your question, as it doesn't do anything for `ft_min_word`. I can see how that sollution should work though. Maybe open an new question with your code, what you tried to implement that sollution, and what doesn't work? Fact of the matter stays that you can _NOT_ change `ft_min_word` at runtime....

Answer (score 2):

Check the length of the search term, then, if it is less than allowed by ft_min_word, use LIKE('%searchterm%')

Even better, if possible, index the first couple of characters of the column and use LIKE('searchterm%')