# MySQL Fulltext Search with short words removal disabled

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, hosting

I am using share hosting on Dreamhost. How can I have the mysql fulltext to search short words with length less than 3? Is there anyway I can do it directly in php?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ft_min_word_len in MySQL on SHARED SERVER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193997/ft-min-word-len-in-mysql-on-shared-server)

Answer (score 1):

IF you are only searching using a string of 3 chars or less then there is no point doing full-text search - you will only need:

```
select * from table where field LIKE'%xxx%'
```

If you are doing a full text search then your search string will be longer than 3 chars which will negate the need for the above.

SO - are you searching for strings of 3 characters or less or not?

Comment: Yes. But I need to use fulltext search for better search result.

Comment: full text search does not work on strings less than 4 characters so you won't get ANY results. MINIMUM string length is 4 for full-text search. To search on strings <4 characters you CANNOT use full-text search.

Answer (score 1):

Full text does work on strings of 4 characters or less but just not by default.  You'll need to tell MySQL to index them by changing ft_min_word_len=2 (if you want to index 2 char words) in your my.cnf file.

Then you'll need to restart MySQL, and rebuild the fulltext indices on the tables in question.

It's possible that some of the words that want to index such as IT might be on the stop word list.  Googling will tell you how to sort out that problem.  IIRC it's just a case of adding them to a text file of words that you want to index from the default stopword list.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use LIKE'%xxx%' in your query - full text doesn't work on <4 chars also has to be myisam table...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But if I add "LIKE" into the fulltext search, it will ruining the search result arrangement in relevant. Is it possible to maintain the search result in relevant arrangement after addin the "LIKE" into the query condition?